# Why does tempdir() give the same result on every core of a fork cluster?

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing, fork

I want to run several bootstrapping samples in parallel. The calculation involves creating a temporary directory for each sample. I use the package `future` with `plan(multisession)`, which automatically creates a fork cluster on my linux machine to run the samples in parallel.

My problem is that `tempdir()` does not return different results for each sample, not even when I `set.seed(.)` differently for each core.

MCVE (this will not work on Windows, because Windows cannot `fork()`):

```
clu <- parallel::makeForkCluster(4)
unlist(parallel::clusterApply(clu, 1:4, 
  function(x){ set.seed(x); tempdir() }))
## [1] "/tmp/Rtmp0uaUin" "/tmp/Rtmp0uaUin" "/tmp/Rtmp0uaUin" "/tmp/Rtmp0uaUin"
```

If I restart R, I get different results, but per session the return values are all equal.

On the other hand, other random functions work fine, at least if I include `set.seed(x)`

```
unlist(parallel::clusterApply(clu, x = 1:4, 
  function(x){ set.seed(x); rnorm(1) }))
##[1] -0.6264538 -0.8969145 -0.9619334  0.2167549

unlist(parallel::clusterApply(clu, x = 1:4, 
  function(x){ rnorm(1) }))
## [1] -1.100044 -1.100044 -1.100044 -1.100044
```

Why does `tempdir()` behave differently than other random functions, and what can I do about it?

Comment: You'll have to generate different prefixes in each parallel process. From the documentation: [*R processes forked by functions such as `mclapply` and `makeForkCluster` in package parallel share a per-session temporary directory. Further, the ‘guaranteed not to be currently in use’ applies only at the time of asking, and two children could ask simultaneously. This is circumvented by ensuring that tempfile calls in different children try different names.*](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tempfile.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from `?tempdir`:

> [...] the per-session temporary directory is created before the interpreter is started.

So the initial R process fixes and creates `tempdir()` and the forked processes inherit that. One possible solution is to create new temp directories based on `tempfile()`:

```
unlist(parallel::mclapply(1:4, function(x){ tempfile(pattern = "dir") }))
#> [1] "/tmp/Rtmpl1ynxV/dir42bb40fa8f75" "/tmp/Rtmpl1ynxV/dir42bc40fa8f75"
#> [3] "/tmp/Rtmpl1ynxV/dir42bb2c930883" "/tmp/Rtmpl1ynxV/dir42bc2c930883"
```

Note that I am using `mclapply` since that handles seeding the RNG by default.